# Rendering issue in code before --

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting, markdown-rendering

[c / c++ most optimized solution needed plz provide the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66881613/c-c-most-optimized-solution-needed-plz-provide-the-solution) (is a terrible question), but has a section of the question where the last line of a code list before a `--` is bold:
[image]

The markdown is

```
# Sample Output

--
root0
[snip...]
2super8
2super9
--
admin0admin
```

So I don't see why this is bold. Even more curious, in the *preview*, it is NOT bold:

[image]

This appears to be some sort of rendering bug, one way or another.

Comment: The bold is possibly due to the alternative markdown for header.

Comment: Ah, that would explain it. It probably shouldn't trigger in a code block, and it should also work in the preview then.

Comment: The code block is being automatically recognized as Markdown because the question is tagged with both [tag:c] and [tag:c++] causing the highlighter having to freely guess which programming language is being used in the post, since there isn’t a unique option. This is basically the same as [this report on “Goodbye, Prettify. Hello highlight.js! Swapping out our Syntax Highlighter”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/355120/289905); and there are a few other reports like this.

Comment: Also reported on MSE: [Some lines of code block are bold when the question has at least two language tags](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/365006/289905).

Answer (score 2):

[@SebastianSimon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4642212/sebastian-simon) pretty much has the correct answer [in their comment above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406349/rendering-issue-in-code-before#comment834052_406349).

I can't vouch for whether their reasoning is perfect, but the code block is indeed being detected as Markdown rather than the intended language, and thus being styled as such:

`lang-md`:

```md
# Sample Output

--
root0
[snip...]
2super8
2super9
--
admin0admin
```

The language is being recognized as Markdown, and being styled as such. All you need to do to keep this from happening is to manually specify the language of the code block. Put the code in a code fence, and [use a language or tag specifier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#how-do-i-use-syntax-highlighting) to tell the highlighter what language to use.

More details on this system, and a full list of supported language IDs, can be found in the "[What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109)" post over on MSE.

As for why the preview didn't match the post... I'm less sure. You could have been experiencing [the built-in delay](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156699/why-is-there-a-delay-before-the-preview-is-syntax-highlighted) that the preview has before displaying highlighting, or it may have just failed to load for some reason, which I've personally experienced too. This could definitely be a bug, or it could be just normal behavior with some connection issues or something thrown in, it's hard to be positive.

Comment: Then this is a bug in the previewer, which didn't guess the same language?

Comment: @MooingDuck Not really a bug in the previewer *or* the renderer, it's just the language guesser making a poor guess in this specific case. It's rendering the selected language perfectly, the algorithm just picked badly; this happens not infrequently. If you see it in the wild, just edit the code block into a fence and define the language directly.

Comment: Clearer: As a user, I consider it a bug when the previewer and the renderer render the same content differently. In this case, it sounds like there's a difference in the language guessing, which should be fixed.

Comment: You're right, I just realized that I totally glossed over the render difference between the preview and the actual post that you mentioned in your post; seeing that as a bug is very fair. There are occasional differences between the preview and final render of posts, and these are bugs which should be recorded and reported.

Comment: @MooingDuck I updated my post accordingly, sorry I missed that part!

Comment: Automatic language resolution isn't done in preview. I personally struggle with preview highlighting in general - it's also a prime reason people edit space blocks to markdown blocks, even if it makes no practical difference. The bug here is that preview struggles with syntax highlighting, really.